# iOS: move and resize UITabbar icons programmatically

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have programmatically set up a `UITabBarController` with 3 views, but the icons in the `UITabBar` aren't looking like what I wanted them to. Is there a way to programmatically resize/move them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons in the `UITabBar` are instances `UITabBarItem` which is a subclass of `UIBarItem`.

`UIBarItem` has a property called `imageInsets` which I think is exactly what you are looking for.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem

I imagine the code will look something like:

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = {
    .top = 3,
    .left = 0,
    .bottom = 4,
    .right = 3
};

self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = insets;
```

You could also just try modifying the raw image file so it sits better in the space.

Comment: tyvm my friend :)) sorry it took me so long to mark it as the correct answer